# What is .1f means in android

Tags: java, android

can anyone explain the code

```
double partialradius = Math.cos(.1f/divide);
```

I want know what is .1f means,
is it 0.1 ?

Comment: `float` literal with value `0.1`. See [Java Language Specification §3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2): *A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d`.* --- Of course, it's stupid to add the `f` in this case, since the division operator (`/`) will coerce the value to `double`, in effect losing precision in the `float` to `double` conversion.

Comment: 0.1 means double and .1f means 0.1 float

Comment: anything with suffix `f/F` is referred as [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html)

Comment: @Andreas yes... my bad edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `.1` resolves to type double in java. And adding `f` you tell compiler that it is of type float.

So no need to cast it!

Comment: Of course, there is no need to cast it or make it a `float` in this case, because it's converted to `double` by the `/` operator, and `(double) .1f` is actually `0.10000000149011612`, not `0.1`, so making the literal a `float` is actually detrimental. Oops!